# How to make Custom UILabel in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

In my project there is huge number of `UIlabel`s. I have created one separate custom class for `UILabel` and I have set all label's properties in that class.

Here my main requirement is some labels' color is white and some labels' text color is black but color is not applying.

### CustomUILabel class:-

```
#import "CustomLabel.h"

@implementation CustomLabel

-(void)layoutSubviews{

    [self setupUI];
}

- (void)setupUI {

    [self setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:14.0]];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}

@end
```

### Main class:-

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController (){

}

@end

@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize label1,label2;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     label1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     label2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: where are to setting uilable color in your code. You are setting textfield textcolor

Comment: set the class of label as "CustomUILabel" in storyboard.

Comment: 1) Always call `[super layoutSubviews];` when you override `layoutSubviews`. 2) You should not be calling `setupUI` from `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: so what should i do explain with code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you override `layoutSubviews`, you must call `[super layoutSubviews]`. But that's not your problem here. The problem is that you're calling `setupUI` in `layoutSubviews`, and you shouldn't. Layout happens after `viewDidLoad`, so your attempt to set the color in `viewDidLoad` gets overridden later during layout, when `setupUI` runs.

You should be calling `setupUI` from the init methods of your subclass:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self setupUI];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setupUI];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And you shouldn't override `layoutSubviews` at all in `CustomLabel`.

Comment: no not applying i am actually creating UILabels programatically in tableList

Comment: CustomLabel * headLabel1 = [[CustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 17, 250, 25)];
    headLabel1.text = [MainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    headLabel1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: What drag and drop process? You just said you're creating the labels programmatically. At any rate, overriding both `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:` should cover all the bases.

Comment: yes fine thanks a lot and for UItextfields also same process?

Comment: @Krish, yes with case of drag & drop, you should change `UILabel` class to your custom label class in Interface Builder. Also, you will need to add `setupUI`  in `awakeFromNib` method. I hope this will cover drag and drop case as well.

Comment: for textfields if i kepp all this code it's not working

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `layoutSubview` method and your `setupUI` method.

`layoutSubviews` is not the proper place to call `setupUI`. `layoutSubviews` can be called many times and is most likely being called a couple of times after `viewDidLoad` is called which is why the colors are being reset back to black.

And always call `[super layoutSubviews];` in your `layoutSubviews` method.

The better place to call your `setupUI` method is from one or more of the appropriate `init...` methods and possibly `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: no not applying i am actually creating UILabels programatically in tableList

Comment: CustomLabel * headLabel1 = [[CustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 17, 250, 25)];
    headLabel1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: Call `setupUI` from the `initWithFrame:` method. Then any color you set after that won't be overwritten.